# How to get batch file to pick a file depending on computer name

Tags: batch-file, cmd, installshield, wds

I created two response files and I want to create a batch file were one of the two response files gets used depending on the computer name. To get the name of a computer, I have been using

`wmic computersystem get name`

I am thinking I have to use IF THEN but I am not so sure.

Comment: Why have you tagged this powershell if you're not using powershell? Would you accept a powershell answer?

Comment: Yes, I would accept a powershell answer. Thanks!

Comment: There is an environment variable `%COMPUTERNAME%` you could check by `if "%COMPUTERNAME%"=="<some_name>" (...) else (...)`

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this with a switch in PowerShell:

```
switch($env:COMPUTERNAME){
    "COMPUTER-1" {
        # use response file for COMPUTER-1
    }
    default {
        # use default response file
    }
}
```

---

A traditional `if`/`else` statement in PowerShell would look like this:

```
if($env:COMPUTERNAME -eq "COMPUTER-1"){
    # use response file for COMPUTER-1
}
else {
    # use default response file 
}
```